Jmeter script for Dynamic value
Hello everyone my issue is in jmeter.
I record the script & I found the dynamic value for example In A request & in replylog showing A request for Correlation.. This is my issue
Note:- Every request firing properly so need to add any request manually.
How to solve this issue please help me.

I can hardly understand you question and where is the "issue", please get familiarized with How do I ask a good question?  and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example documentation chapters.
If you need our help with regards to properly configuring JMeter Post-Processor for extracting the dynamic value - please provide at least partial (or better full) response and as text, not as the image and indicate which part of it you want to extract.
If response contains sensitive data you can either fake it or give a try JMeter Correlation Recorder Plugin which has auto-correlation feature so there is a chance that it will generate the good test configuration for you

thanks a lot for your response. my teamet told you need to take before request response from developer tool and add Json extractor
